# Casting object causes exception

Tags: c#

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dgvAttendance.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    total += Convert.ToInt32(dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells[4]);
}
txtWH.Text = total.ToString();
```

How can I fix this exception occurring in my codes?

Comment: What is the exception ?? Please write what you are trying to do? what are the results and what is expected?

Comment: System.invalidCast Exception. i want to sum all the values in a partircular column in database example i have this WokHours columns and i want to add all the values in that column.

Comment: Please show the *complete* exception - and note that you dont have any actual casts in your code. (You've got a call to `Convert.ToInt32`, but that's not an actual cast.)

Comment: @TikboyPengan: You said it contains WorkHours and I expected it might have values in "##:##" Format.

Comment: @Shweta Pathak Sorry its okay now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
total += Convert.ToInt32(dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
```

I'm not sure what the class is of `dgvAttendance`, but if it's a `DataGridView` then what you're accessing with `Cells[4]` is the `DataGridViewCell`, not the value within.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the text of the cell, not the cell itself:

```
total += Convert.ToInt32(dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
```